# Filtering by method value - too many SQL variables error

Tags: python, django

One of my views needs to filter a queryset by a method value, example:

```
invoices_ids = list(map(lambda inv: inv.id, filter(lambda inv: inv.status().lower() == request['status'], invoices)))
invoices = invoices.filter(id__in = invoices_ids)
```

The status method comes from something like this:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    (...)

    def status(self):
        if self.canceled:
            return 'Canceled'
        elif self.passed_date:
            return 'Passed'
        elif self.req_date:
            return 'Requested'
        return 'Inserted'
```

Problem is this kind of filtering gives me an OperationalError "too many SQL variables".. I guess there are too many `invoices` with a specific status, and the filter `id__in` gets a gigantic list.

How can i overcome this? (To filter by `status` without having to save into another model variable)

Comment: What are `self.canceled`, `self.passed_date` and `self.req_date`? Are they fields with `null=True`? Please add them to your question.

Comment: Nevermind, you just gave me a great idea! Thanks :D